# How to filter chunked array in Vue's computed property?

Tags: vue.js

I have a bunch of data fetched from a computed property and I want to make it filterable in `name` via the search input.

The data looks like this (from vue devtools):

```
chunkedAirlines: Array[6]
    0: Array[6]
      0: Object
        id: 1
        name: "Lorem ipsum 1"
      1: Object
        id: 2
        name: "Lorem ipsum 2"
      ...

    1: Array[6]
      0: Object
        id: 3
        name: "Lorem ipsum 3"
      1: Object
        id: 4
        name: "Lorem ipsum 4"
      ...
```

I already tried solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027946/filter-array-by-nested-value-that-meets-certain-condition-in-vue) but I still cannot get it work as I wanted. The value inside `chunkedAirlines` does not updated on key up.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-white text-muted">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="search-input"
                        class="form-control border-left-0"
                        placeholder="Find airline..."
                        aria-label="Airline"
                        aria-describedby="search-airline-button"
                        v-model="search"
                        @keyup="findAirline">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-right mr-4">
                    <span class="fas fa-plus-circle mr-1"></span>
                    New Airline
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div 
            class="row"
            v-for="airlines in chunkedAirlines"
            :key="airlines.key">
            <div
                class="col-md-4"
                v-for="airline in airlines"
                :key="airline.id">
                <a
                    :href="'/airlines/' + airline.slug"
                    class="card airline-card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img :src="airline.icon" :alt="airline.name + ' icon'" height="100" class="rounded">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize mb-0 mt-3">{{ airline.name }}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            airlines: [],
            search: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        chunkedAirlines() {
            return _.chunk(this.airlines.data, 6)
        },
        findAirline() {
            return this.chunkedAirlines.filter(items => {
                return items.filter((airline) => {
                    return airline.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                })
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/airlines')
        .then(response => {
            this.airlines = response.data
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

Here's a working example:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-white text-muted">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="search-input"
                        class="form-control border-left-0"
                        placeholder="Find airline..."
                        aria-label="Airline"
                        aria-describedby="search-airline-button"
                        v-model="search">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-right mr-4">
                    <span class="fas fa-plus-circle mr-1"></span>
                    New Airline
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div 
            class="row"
            v-for="airlines in chunkedAirlines"
            :key="airlines.key">
            <div
                class="col-md-4"
                v-for="airline in airlines"
                :key="airline.id">
                <a
                    :href="'/airlines/' + airline.slug"
                    class="card airline-card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img :src="airline.icon" :alt="airline.name + ' icon'" height="100" class="rounded">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize mb-0 mt-3">{{ airline.name }}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            airlines: [],
            search: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        chunkedAirlines() {
            if (this.search && this.search.length > 0) {
              return _.chunk(this.airlines.data, 6).filter(items => {
                  return items.filter((airline) => {
                      return airline.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                  })
              })
            } else {
                return _.chunk(this.airlines.data, 6)
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/airlines')
        .then(response => {
            this.airlines = response.data
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

This way You simply have your search input bind to the search variable in your data object, then computed property gets updated if user searches something and shows filtered data, or if theres no search returns the items normally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm.. already tried that too and got this error `TypeError: handler.apply is not a function` :(

Comment: sorry, my fault.. I keep placing `@keyup` function which is not necessary. I don't know why the error is gone but the computed property does not get updated.

Comment: fixed by chunking the whole filter result.